# Elm - absolute position of an element

Tags: css, position, element, elm

Given the following hypothetical function:

```
bowlingBall : Form -> Signal Element
bowlingBall shape =
  makeMovable shape
```

How would one retrieve the absolute position of

`bowlingBall greenFilledCircle`?

I've noticed that when I debug a compiled page containing a drag-able element, chrome keeps track of the position under the property `transform: matrix(...)` - is this something we can tap into using elm functions, or does some interop need to be employed?

Comment: One thought was that a defined element like `bowlingBall` above must be moved via a sequence of commands - keeping record of the update should give the current position of the element.

Comment: Another thought is that the correct way to do this in JS is apparently using `getBoundingClientRect(bowlingBall)` - however the JS would need to be embedded into an html file for interop - it may be better to use the above approach instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do directly what you're asking for `Element`s. There's a [pull request](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/pull/307) which would allow you to do this, but it hasn't been merged in yet.

There likewise isn't a good way of directly inspecting the position of a `Form` either.

I've run into a similar issue in the past and the way I've tackled it is to hold the position of my various items in my model and do all my position manipulations with regard to that position.

This isn't perfect; in particular the cumbersome conversion between the coordinate systems used by `Mouse` and the coordinate system used by `Form`s becomes much more annoying without this capability, especially if your `Form`s don't happen to inhabit a canvas at the upper-left corner of your window.

Comment: Thanks, coincidentally the PR was bumped on the order of 1 min around the time of your answer.